# Aligning issue with overline

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

[image]

Is it possible to align the p and q as well as the ones vertically?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \begin{document}
    $z_1^p\overline{z_1}^q$
    \end{document}
```

Comment: ...try with `$z_1^p \overline{\smash{z^{\phantom{p}}_1}\vphantom{z}}^q_{\phantom{1}}$`.

Comment: ... or `$z_1^p\overline{z_1}_{\vphantom{1}}^q$` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
$z_1^p\overline{z}_1^{\,q}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay I think I'll just use $z_1^p\overline{z}_1^q$. Thanks to all.

Comment: I did it and the `q` is very close to the top line ...

Comment: Yes your right. Maybe I'll change this eventually, now that I see it...

Comment: Good luck .....

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, `\widebar`, borrowed from `mathabx`, looks nicer tha `\overline`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}

\begin{document}

\[ z_1^p \widebar{z}_1^{\mkern1.5mu q} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]