# Align \overline in equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

I'm quite new to LaTeX and struggling with the alignment in math mode. Is there any way to nicely align the bar in my equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

We denote by
\begin{equation}
    \text{OOB-MSE} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - \bar{\widehat{y}}_{i \: \text{OOB}})^2,
\end{equation}
the so-called out-of-bag mean square error, where $\overline{\widehat{y}}_{i \: \text{OOB}}$ is the averaged... 

\end{document}
```

I also tried the command from another similar question ([Aligning issue with overline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453229/aligning-issue-with-overline)) but it's much smaller than the overline bar and still not really aligned..

```
\newcommand{\myol}[2][3]{{}\mkern#1mu\overline{\mkern-#1mu#2}}
```

Thanks!

The first bar in the picture uses the \bar command and the second uses the \overline command. Both aren't nicely aligned.
[image: Above is the usual \bar command and below the \overline command]

Comment: It might be a good idea to add an image as well

Comment: I get a much better result with `\bar{\hat{y}}`

Comment: I don't like just the \hat command, I find it too narrow...

Comment: @cactus_splines: the `mathabx` package defines  `\widebar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I write my proposal using `accents` package. I have used
this trick

```
\accentset{\mkern2.55mu\_}{\widehat{y}}
```

to have the bar and centering the widehat. Of course you can create a macro, but the advice that if you change the letter `y` for example you must change the value of `\mkern2.55mu`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}

We denote by
\begin{equation}
    \textup{OOB-MSE} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - \accentset{\mkern2.55mu\_}{\widehat{y}}_{i \: \textup{OOB}})^2,
\end{equation}
the so-called out-of-bag mean square error, where $\accentset{\mkern2.55mu\_}{\widehat{y}}_{i \: \textup{OOB}}$ is the averaged... 

\end{document}
```

[image]